# Targeting Parentnodes JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple ul with some li items with some of them having a child ul inside them.

```
<ul class="wrapper">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>subLink1</li>
            <li>subLink2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link4</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>subLink1</li>
            <li>subLink2</li>
            <li>subLink3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to grab the li elements that have the subnav ul as a child and store them in a variable.

Im having trouble grabbing them with what I have so far. I get an undefined error message in the console:

```
const findTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper li .subnav');
const triggers = findTriggers.parentNode;
console.log(triggers);
```

Im sure its something simple Ive overlooked but if anyone has any pointers then that would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Jools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to get all the items you need. in my example I used a `forEach` method.

> The Element method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) **NodeList** representing a list of elements matching the specified group of selectors which are descendants of the element on which the method was called.

I specified the argument `"curr"` as the current element in the array.

```js
const findTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper li .subnav");

findTriggers.forEach(curr => {
    const triggers = curr.parentNode;
    console.log(triggers.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link1</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>subLink1</li>
            <li>subLink2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link4</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>subLink1</li>
            <li>subLink2</li>
            <li>subLink3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```